# Cygwin and Vim - Command Prompt is capturing mouse wheel scrolling and not Vim

Tags: vim, cygwin, console-application

So I have the setting in my ~/.vimrc file set correctly

```
set mouse=a
set ttymouse=xterm2
```

However, when I am using vim and I try scrolling with my mouse wheel, the scroll bars on the command prompt move instead of vim scrolling internally.  This makes a mess for vim, especially when my I am moving throughout my code.

This was working before and may be related to the Command Prompt Settings - although I am not sure which ones.

I have also tried to go through the Control Panel's Mouse Settings and give `gvim` an exception, but I don't have that option in Windows 7.

The version of Cygwin and vim are pretty recent.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you simple miss the option:

```
 se mouse=a
```

I might be oversimplifying though since I use mintty. Mintty can just be installed from the cygwin setup.exe. Mintty has huge advantages anyway:

- performance
- standards compliance
- screen support (you can detach/reattach without problems, woot!)
- functioning full-screen support (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Anywhoo, is that a typo?  `se mouse=a` should be `set mouse=a`

Comment: Tried mintty.  A lot better then pure Cygwin, however it does not work with the trackpad but does work with the mousewheel.  Go figure

Comment: @kevjames3 The trackpad issue is thanks to the Synaptics driver. When it sees a window with an inactive scrollbar, as you get with mintty when an application like vim switches it to the so-called alternate screen, the Synaptics driver no longer bothers sending scrolling events to the window. A somewhat less than ideal workaround is to switch off the scrollbar on the Window page of mintty's options.

Comment: @ak2: interesting. I find scrollbars unnecessary distractions, which explains why I never had this issue (they're always hidden/disabled with me). Anyway, with Vim you have `20%` and `C-g` navigation!

Comment: @kevjames3: I just noticed the other question. No that was not a typo. In vim, commands can always be abbreviated, and `se` is so ubiquitously used, I don't even notice it anymore. (Now, "anywhoo"...: was _that_ a typo?)